# ECommonCalendarError: Failed to set calendar date or time

Tags: delphi, runtime-error, delphi-2009

I started a new Delphi application, I dropped a `TDateTimePicker` on the main form, and I added this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 DateTimePicker1.MaxDate:= Now - 9;
 DateTimePicker1.Date:= Now - 10;
end;
```

When I run the program and trying to change the date using `UP ARROW` from the keyboard, I get this error message. But if I change the date with the `MOUSE` to the last possible date, I don't receive the error message. And after that I can change the date with the arrow key too.

I do not understand what is wrong and how to correct this problem.

**Update:**
I found another situation when that error occurs: When I drop down the list and close it again, without selecting anything, but with these settings:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var D:TDate;
begin
 D:= Date;
 DateTimePicker1.Date:= D;
 DateTimePicker1.MaxDate:= D;
end;
```

Comment: It's a VCL bug which was fixed in later release. In the `CNNotify` method when the `DTN_DATETIMECHANGE` notification arrives is missing setting of the `FChanging` flag.

Comment: The underlying problem is that `DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME` fails to set date time because of existing time portion (which overlaps maximum datetime).

Comment: And is nothing I can do about it ? A workaround or something... :( If I could trigger somehow that thing that happends whend I choose the date with the mouse... After I do that, everything works fine...

Comment: You can modify VCL source or externally use e.g. [intercept class like this](https://pastebin.com/B4T7zbKb).

Comment: Now I get that error when I drop down the list with the mouse and close it again.

Comment: Does it happen if you remove that intercept? I cannot reproduce that (up to date Windows 7, Delphi 2009). It's a different notification, `DTN_CLOSEUP`.

Comment: It seems that the new error (dropping the list and close it again, without selecting anything) it's not from your intercept class, because it still happens if I remove it. But the code to reproduce it it's a little different. See my update from this question.

Comment: It is the same underlying problem. When setting only `Date` property, the date portion is replaced, but the time remains (and so long date and time is passed to the `DateTime_SetSystemTime` macro, it fails due to overflowing max limit which results in that exception). One way to workaround both issues is zeroing `Time`, or setting `DateTime` property instead of `Date`.

Comment: Perfect ! Now everything it's working fine. Thank you so much ! You can post it as an answer. I will definitely accept it !

Comment: Aha, now I see the problem. They missed to set 23:59:59 time portion in the `SetMaxDate` setter. That was fixed in some later Delphi release. Anyway, you're welcome! I'll try to sum up this into an answer later on (busy now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in Delphi 2009 VCL. The problem is that setter for the [**MaxDate**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.MaxDate) property did not add time portion of 23:59:59 to the maximum range limit. Then, when one left the [**Time**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.Time) property on time different from 00:00:00 and set only the [**Date**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.Date) property the [**DateTime_SetSystemTime**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-datetime_setsystemtime) macro failed because of a date time overflow of the date time range (which led to that exception).

To avoid this you can reset the [**Time**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.Time) property to 00:00:00, or assign date only (keeping time portion zeroed) to the [**DateTime**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.DateTime) property.